# How to Delete an entry based on Combining TWO COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-delete

I have a table called Customer containing Id, Firstname, Lastname, Phone as their respective columns.

Now I want to delete an entry from the table Using Fullname.

```
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE exists (SELECT * Id,CONCAT(Firstname," ",Lastname) as wholename 
           from customer where wholename ="Andre Russel");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE CONCAT(Firstname,' ',Lastname) = 'Andre Russel'
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks.. it worked :) I have one more doubt if u dont mind.

Comment: @Dumbo Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. If your question is pertinent to the original one, then I'll be glad to help here. Otherwise, if you have another question, try writing a separate post.